# If data contains commas, how to store it in csv?

Tags: java, algorithm

If the task is to create a csv file out of some data where commas may be present, is there a way to do it without later confusing which comma is a delimiter and which comma is part of a value?

Obviously, we can use a different delimiter, replace all occurrences, or replace the original comma with something else, but for the purpose of this question let's say that modifying the original data is not an option and a comma is the only delimiter allowed.

How would you approach something like this? Would it be easier to create the xls instead? Can you recommend any java libraries that handle this well?

Comment: javacsv handles this quite well (with " around the values)

Comment: Have you read CSV format documentation? It consider such case

Comment: I normally see CSVs like this quoting the whole field in single/double-quotes to get round that problem. You'd need to escape any of those within the field though.

Comment: Are the content that contains the data inside quoted test such as `123,123,'abc,123,123',a`?

Comment: @sil That assumes there's a single authoritative reference for CSV. Very funny!

Comment: If you're worrying about this, you're probably Doing It Wrong. Use a library that handles it for you.

Comment: @NickJohnson: *"That assumes there's a single authoritative reference for CSV"* There's [the RFC](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Right. But my point was that CSV is such a widespread and largely informal 'format' that no one spec actually encompasses everything you'll find labelled as 'CSV'.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A true CSV reader should be able to handle this; the values should be in quotes, e.g.:

```
one,two,"a, b, c",four
```

...per item #6 in [Section 2 of the RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180#section-2).

Comment: This is how Microsoft Excel does it.

Answer (score 3):

While there's no single CSV standard, the usual convention is to surround entries containing commas in double quotes (i.e. `"`).

Prempting the next question: What to do if your data contains a double quote? In this case they are usually substituted for a **pair** of double quotes.

While I hate to cite wikipedia as a source, they do have a pretty good roundup of [basic rules and examples](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#Basic_rules_and_examples) for CSV formatting.

Answer (score 2):

I would either use a different delimiter or use a library like [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/).

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way is to use Apache POI: http://poi.apache.org/
You can easily create XLS documents without much hassle.

However, if you really need CSV and not XLS, you can surround the value with quotes. This should also solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you work with `,` as separator and `'` as quote. So your values would look like:

```
foo, 'bar, baz', iik, aje
```

Answer (score 0):

> the task is to create a csv file

Actually an impossible task, since [there is no such thing as "a CSV" file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#Lack_of_a_standard). Different Microsoft produces have used different (subtly different, I grant) formats and named them all "CSV". As most spreadsheets can read [delimiter separated value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delimiter-separated_values) (DSV) files, you might be better writing one of those.